# Encoding working on a NSString but not on others

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring, nsdictionary

Well this is bizarre and I can't find any explanation.
The issue is that I am "transforming" a object `property` to a value into a `NSDictionary` and in a specific value it "encodes" a "special character" but on other values it doesn't.

This is the .h file for the object where I declare the properties:

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "ModelObject.h"

@interface CheckinObject : ModelObject
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *num;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *date;
```

This is the .m file, where I synthesize and put it into a NSDictionary:

```
@implementation CheckinObject
@synthesize name;
@synthesize num;
@synthesize date;

//bunch of other uninteresting code

    - (NSDictionary*)toDictionary {
        NSLog(@"=> self.num : %@", self.num);
        NSDictionary *dic = @{
                              @"date"   :self.date,
                              @"name"   :self.name,
                              @"num" :self.num
                              };
        NSLog(@"=> dic.num : %@", dic[@"num"]);
        NSLog(@"=> dic     : %@", dic);
        return dic;
    }
```

This is the output:

```
2016-05-25 21:03:44.333 FoodTruckApp[1320:614394] => self.num : 23–187
2016-05-25 21:03:44.334 FoodTruckApp[1320:614394] => dic.num : 23–187
2016-05-25 21:03:44.335 FoodTruckApp[1320:614394] => dic     : {
    date = "2016-05-25 21:03:44";
    name = "Alameda dos Carvalhos";
    num = "23\U2013187";
}
```

Any thought on what I might be missing here?
Cheers.

Comment: Ignore the log output of `NSDictionary` and other classes. For some confusing reason, logging such things results in mysterious quotes and character encodings. None of that is in the actual data.

Comment: Agreed with @rmaddy. `NSLog` is using `description`, which does not promise any particular format. It only tries to be useful for debugging purposes. If you really need to know what's in the dictionary, write your own printing logic.

Comment: It looks like the string values from the dictionary are displayed in UTF8. NSLog can be misleading in various ways. This is a new on on me. `NSDates` are another one, since dates display in UTC.

Comment: There would be 10,000 fewer questions on Stack Overflow if logging `NSDate` and collections classes weren't so misleading.

Comment: Contrary to what rmaddy says, it *is* the "actual data", but when an object is dumped via the `description` method any string values are converted to UTF8.  This behavior is actually quite well defined, just often surprising.

Comment: @HotLicks Welcome back. Yeah, I may have exaggerated that statement a bit. :) There is no reason why the `description` method can't simply show the actual string. Why does it need to convert many Unicode characters to the `\Uxxxx` encoded value? Why does it need to conditionally put values in quotes? Just quote every value or no values. It makes debugging really difficult for people working in languages in other alphabets.

Comment: hey, @rmaddy . The problem is that I'm POSTING this dictionary to my web server it messes up my JSON file and it doesn't work ): Any other ideas?

Comment: @FelipeGringo Nothing in your question shows any information about how you are posting the dictionary or any JSON. If you are having trouble with that, you should update your question appropriately.

Comment: @rmaddy but if the value in the NSDictionary was correct then PHP or POSTING part is irrelevant.

Comment: There is no way for anyone here to know since you have not provided any information at all regarding your issue. So far your question shows some output from logging an `NSDictionary`. But it seems your actual issue is about sending the dictionary as JSON to a server. If you want help with that issue you need to completely redo your question with details relevant to that problem.